# java protobuf3 what is `buildPartial` used for?

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

As described in this document(https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Message.Builder.html#buildPartial--) `Like MessageLite.Builder.build(), but does not throw an exception if the message is missing required fields. Instead, a partial message is returned`

I guess that's a legacy API from proto2? since `required` keyword is removed in proto3, but they're not marking this API as deprecated, then in which case we should use this?

Answer (score 1):

---

This allows to easily supply class instance to the unit test environment. Allowing to avoid complex mocking/class construction.